# Column space and null space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

> Let $A\in M_{5,7}(\mathbb{R})$ be a matrix such that $Ax=b$ has solution for every $b$.

I have to say what this information tells me about column- and null-space and rows of a matrix. The only thing I can think of is that column-space can have dimension $1$ to $5$ and null-space dimension can be deduced using rank-nullity theorem.

Is there something more to see here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Column space is all of $\mathbb{R}^5$ since any $b\in \mathbb{R}^5$ appears in the range of $A$.   Thus rank is 5, and so the rank-nullity theorem says $5+\mathrm{nullity}=7$, thus $\mathrm{nullity}=2$.